Why isotropic pairing $〈, 〉$ induces　$B\cong B^*\stackrel{f^*}{\to}A^*$ and $B\to \text{Coker}f \hookrightarrow A^* $ coincides as a map
Let $A,B$ be abelian groups. $A^*$ be its dual, that is, $A^*=\text{Hom}(A,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$. Suppose there is a non-degenerate pairing $〈,〉: B\times B \to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ and this pairing induces an isomorphism　 $B\cong B^*$.
Let $f : A\to B$ be a group homomorphism.
Suppose the condition that $〈f(a),f(a')〉=0, \forall a,a'\in A\times A$ , in other words, pairing $〈,〉$ is isotropic with respect to $A$.
I want to prove
$B\cong B^*\stackrel{f^*}{\to}A^*$  and $B\to \text{Coker}f \hookrightarrow A^* $ coincides as a map under the condition that $A\to B\stackrel{f^*}{\to} A^*$ is an exact sequence.
How can I prove this ?
I want to prove

$B\cong B^*\stackrel{f^*}{\to}A^*$  and
$B\to \text{Coker}f \hookrightarrow A^*$ coincides
as a map.

Simply following the mapping correspondence is not enough to prove this claim. Am I missing some fact about pairing?

The map $\phi : \operatorname{Coker}f \to A^*$ is defined as $[b] \mapsto \left(a \mapsto \langle b, f(a) \rangle\right)$, right ? So this is straightforward checking that the two morphisms coincide. However, I'm not sure that this map is an inclusion when $f$ is not surjective... can you see why ?
Edit : assuming that $A \to B \to A^*$ is exact, we have indeed $\operatorname{Coker}f \hookrightarrow A^*$. However, we do not need this hypothesis to show that the two maps coincide. Having verified that $\phi$ is well defined (using the assumption that the pairing is isotropic with respect to $A$), we have to see how is defined $B \simeq B^* \to A^*$, but this is just the composition of the two maps $b \in B \mapsto (b' \mapsto \langle b, b' \rangle) \in B^*$ and $l \in B^* \mapsto l \circ f \in A^*$. By putting things in order, we get that the application defined so is simply $b \in B \mapsto (a \mapsto \langle b, f(a) \rangle) \in A^*$. Now the map $B \to \operatorname{Coker} f \to A^*$ is just the composition of $\phi$ with the projection $B \to \operatorname{Coker} f$, which simply gives $b \mapsto \phi([b]) = (a \mapsto \langle b, f(a) \rangle)$.

Could you elaborate on the straightforward checking ? For the latter, I think two exact sequences $A\to B\stackrel{f^}{\to} A^$ and $A\to B\to \text{coker}f$　and $A=A$ and $B\cong B^*$ imply the induced map $\iota$ is injective.

Sorry, I forgot to add the condition that the first sequence in my above comment is exact ! I edited my question.

No problem. In fact, you need this assumption to see that the arrow $\operatorname{Coker} f \to A^*$ is an inclusion, otherwise this is not true in general. Nevertheless, you don't need this assumption to show that the two maps coincide.

To summerize, commutativeness is just the definition of Φ, and we use isotropicness to define Φ. But if we assume exatness of the sequence, Φ is autmatically well defined  and injective and there is nothing to prove. Is my understanding correct？

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "commutativeness is just the definition of $\phi$". This map is always well defined when we have this isotropicness assumption but it is not necessarily injective. To get the injectivity, we need the exactness of the above sequence.

I mean, you and I defined $\phi$ as the composition of lifts from $\text{Coker}f$ to $B$ and $B\cong B^\stackrel{f}{\to}A^$. If we assume the exactness of $A\stackrel{f}{\to}B\cong B^\stackrel{f^}{\to}A^*$, well-definedness and injectiveness of $\phi$ follows. Do I understand correctly ?
